# Change Title button destination on Beamer

Tags: beamer, navigation

I noticed that the Title at the bottom of the presentation (at least it is there with the Madrid theme) is a button that goes to the title frame. In the title frame it goes to the last slide before the appendix.

Is there a way to change those links such that on the title frame it goes to the first frame (and maybe choose with slide) of the appendix?

I have my backup slides in the appendix and I would like to be able to quickly jump to them and back to my talk if someone ask a question. I don't like the way the beamer buttons look in the main slides, but I have them in the backup slides because I don't care how they look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the definition of `\insertshorttitle` and change the link to a destination  of your choice.

The following example links to the second slide of a frame labelled `foo`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usetheme{Madrid}

\title{text}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\insertshorttitle[1][]{%
  \beamer@setupshort{#1}%
  \let\thanks=\@gobble%
  \ifnum\c@page=1%
%    \hyperlinkpresentationend{\beamer@insertshort{\beamer@shorttitle}}%
    \hyperlink{foo<2>}{\beamer@insertshort{\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \else%
    \hyperlinkpresentationstart{\beamer@insertshort{\beamer@shorttitle}}%
  \fi}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\titlepage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
content...
\end{frame}

\appendix

\begin{frame}[label=foo]
appendix
\pause
appendix2
\end{frame}


\end{document}
```